# Imageview Interactive-water-effect android

Tags: android

I want imageview animation like some water live wallpaper animation from google play shop,but ,i need animation ripple effect in imageview on myproject.if you don't understand my requirement i want imageview animation like below example on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073/Interactive-water-effect

if it is possible or not possible for implement a imageview. if possible how do this? any one help with me greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That project you linked (and probably anything with this effect) is going to use [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) (not `Canvas` and `.onDraw();`). You wont be able to use an `ImageView` but you can use a `GLSurfaceView`, which shouldn't cause too much trouble. I am not an expert on the subject but the link you gave has excellent code fragments to get you started.

Answer (score -1):

I'm quite sure that you could achieve something like that by extending the ImageView class and messing around in the .onDraw() method, calling .invalidate() constantly and applying animations. But I'm also quite sure that it'd be awfully slow/laggy and look like hell.

I recommend using a SurfaceView to achieve such an effect.

Comment: can u give any code or tutorial!